# jQuery plugin to fit text into a width/height defined element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I know about fitText.js and bigText.js, but neither are meant for a multiple line headline (bigText can do multiple lines, but you have to wrap each line in a div, which won't work here). Put simply, give an `<h1>` with `width: 200px; height: 175px;` is there a jQuery plugin that will dynamically resize the text until it's all visible?

Something like this: `<h1>My Short Headline</h1>` would be large, but something like `<h1>My Somewhat Longer Headline That Needs To Be Completely Visible With No Truncation</h1>` would be quite a bit smaller. Know of anything that would do the trick?

Comment: Do you want it to wrap to the next line or all-in-one-line fit?

Comment: Wrap to fill the height and width. If I wanted it on one line, fitText.js would be perfect.

Comment: What makes "rolling your own" more complicated than hunting for a plug-in?

Answer (score 6):

Came up with my own solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bjork24/VQEC9/

Now I just need to throw it into a plugin and I'll be good to go.

Comment: Have you made this a plugin yet? I'd prefer downloading one than copying and implementing this.

Comment: Would love to see this as a plugin too!